# Calling method on pageElement fails with error "TypeError: Cannot find function"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api

I'm trying to write a script that looks at each pageElement on each slide of a presentation and outputs the source URL of any IMAGE elements. However, I'm stuck at the most elementary stage: any time I call a [documented method of pageElement](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/page-element), I get an error like:

> TypeError: Cannot find function getPageElementType in object {"transform":

It seems as if `slide.pageElements[i]` is returning a plain data object, like a JSON file devoid of any function prototypes. I can't call any of the standard object methods, even things like `getHeight()`, etc.

This is a code stub I can't get to run without error:

```js
function test() {
  var presentationId = INSERT_ID_HERE;
  var presentation = Slides.Presentations.get(presentationId);
  var slides = presentation.slides;
  slides[0].pageElements[0].getPageElementType();
}
```

I'm testing this against a presentation with a single slides with two elements on it (one of which is an image). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Apps Script Slides Service [`SlidesApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/) methods on the result of the Slides API (the "advanced service" client library [`Slides`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/slides)). The Slides API indeed returns JSON representations, while the Slides Service returns objects of defined type, with class methods.

You can review the JSON resource representations on the API site:https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/